# rxjs momentjs filter last 30 days

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, momentjs, akita

I have an object array using the following model:

export interface Data {
    id: number
    qt: number
    date: string
}

I use Akita's store and I would like to filter my object table so that I only have the results for the last 30 days.

```
    qtLastMonth(): Observable<Data[]> {
    return this.selectAll().pipe(
        map((allDatas) => allDatas.filter(data => 
            moment(data.date).format('DD-MM-YYYY') > 
            moment().subtract(30, "days").format('DD-MM-YYYY'))
        ))
}
```

However I get an output of an object table with dates later than the last 30 days ...

Maybe something is missing?

Comment: Try without the format moment(data.date) > moment().subtract(30, “days”)

Answer (score 0):

As @Anthony recommended you have to remove `format` as it would compare strings.
Without it, predicate will be evaluated based on [`obj.valueOf()` Unix Timestamp](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/) values.

```js
const { of , operators: {
    map
  }
} = rxjs;


const selectAll = () => of (Array(10).fill(0).map((pr, index) => ({
  date: moment().subtract(25 + index, 'days').toDate()
})))

selectAll().pipe(
    map((allDatas) => {
      const monthAgo = moment().subtract(30, "days");
      return allDatas.filter(({
        date
      }) => moment(date) > monthAgo)
      // }) => moment(date).valueOf() > monthAgo.valueOf()) // equivalent
    }))
  .subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```